# Does Dalvik create stacks to manage threads

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik, vm-implementation, android-runtime

Unlike JVMs, which are simple **stack-based** machines, the Dalvik VM uses a **register-based** — which requires fewer instructions, avoids unnecessary memory access — resulting in better performance code.

But how does Dalvik manage thread stacks? Does it create a stack for a thread?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The "registers" are just locations on the call stack. When you call into a method, it allocates however much space is needed on the stack to hold the "registers" for the method being called.